# How to explicitly call destructor of a class in Turbo C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, destructor, turbo-c++

I'm trying to call the destructor of a class explicitly in Turbo C++:

```
A a;
a.~A();
```

But it's showing an error:

> Member identifier expected.

Is there any way to explicitly call a destructor in Turbo C++?

Comment: It compiles fine on a compiler from this millenium http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c04b9139cc4e8794 (it has undefined behaviour, though, but that is a different matter)

Comment: Destructor will be automatically called when the object goes out of scope (in your case, when the execution of the main function finishes, as `a` is a local variable in `main`). You don't to need to explicitly call it.

Comment: Why do you want to call the destructor explicitly?

Comment: so is there any problem with compiler i'm currently using, it's turbo c++

Comment: @ShreyasA: Yes, your compiler is too old. Just like nobody uses MS-DOS anymore, you should not use it.

Comment: @ShreyasA Consider donating that compiler to some museum, they might be really happy to see one of those again ;) (Note: no offense intended. Try GCC or LLVM/Clang, those are the state-of-the-art compilers and they are free).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this link](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/cplusplus/9788131703830/7dot-constructors-and-destructors/navpoint147), it seems you actually can do it, the valid format is:

```
A a;
// a.~A(); // Wrong - Member identifier expected
a.A::~A(); // Valid
```

But I don't have a Turbo C++ compiler handy to test it, so you'll have to test it.

**[Edit]**

OP tested it, it works.

Comment: Btw, I've edited your question a bit, is the edit good, does it reflect what you wanted to ask?

Comment: yeah it's small and precise. Though i've added destructor tag to it

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to call destructor explicitly, when an object with `automatic duration` goes out of scope, its destructor will be called implicitly.

```
void main()
{
    A a;
    //a.~A();  // you need to comment out this line
} // a.~A() is called again, you try to destroy an object twice.
```

Comment: true, but not answering the question.

Comment: @Walter what did I miss?

Comment: yeah that's correct but take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884168/c-destructor-being-called-twice?rq=1

Comment: I just realise that there is no question ... Should close it. Anyway, I understood the question to be *why did my attempt fail to call the destructor explicitly* (which in this particular example makes no sense, but may be useful otherwise).

Comment: I think this is a good answer. The question seems like an XY question.

Answer (score 3):

While @billz is right that you don't have to call it explicitly, the line *itself* should be valid. A destructor is a regular method and can be called like that. This can be useful if you implement your own `operator new` and `operator delete` but in your case, just stick with billz answer.

The problem which leads to an error message seems to be that you have a too-old compiler, as evidenced by `<iostream.h>` or `void main()`. Fixing the old-school-stuff (but not the `a.~A();`) the code compiles with GCC 4.8.

Comment: yeah i think thats the reason because http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c04b9139cc4e8794 is running perfectly

Comment: I think a.~A(); causes virtual destructor call and a.A::~A(); causes nonvirtual destructor call.

Comment: @Johny Only if `~A` is virtual which in the OPs example it is not. And if it is virtual, you are right but I also fail to see how this is relevant here.

Comment: There's nothing new about `a.~A()`.  This worked in compilers I was using as early as 1991.  (IIRC, g++ had a bug which meant that it didn't work with it.  But that bug has been fixed ages ago.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I wasn't implying that it's new, I was only saying that bugs in such a basic area are more likely to be caused by old compilers. An someone else already commented, compilers from this millenea don't have problems with that. :)

Comment: You will _not_ use a an explicit destructor if you implement your own `operator new` and `operator delete`.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, following code works well

```
 #include <iostream>

 class A
 {
    public:
     A() { }
     ~A() { std::cout<<"\n ~A()"; }
 };

 int main()
 {

      A a;
      a.A::~A();
      return 0;
  }
```

But beware of Calling the D'tor explicitly. Because compiler will insert the code for an auto obejcts that are inside the function. In the above code will result in calling the D'tor twice i.e

```
 int main()
 {
   A a;
   a.A::~(); //which we provided
   a.A::~(); // provided by the compiler for auto objects
   return 0;
 }
```

We have to explicitly call the D'tor only for the placment new operator [here for more details](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler doesn't allow the standard syntax for an explicit destructor call, then it probably doesn't allow you to do that.

Your compiler is about twenty years old, and the language has been through at least two major revisions since then. I don't have enough historical knowledge (or interest) to know whether its dialect is supposed to allow explicit destruction; but if you want to write modern(ish) C++ then you'll need a modern(ish) compiler.

Comment: Explicit destruction has been in the language at least since CFront 2.1 (late 1980's).  IIRC, g++ had a bug which meant that you had to write `a.A::~A()`, but that would be version 1.49 or 2.1.2; it certainly worked in 2.95.2 (or something like that).  We're at something like 4.8 now, so that means that it has been fixed for a long, long time.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks for the historical context; so it seems the problem is with whichever dialect this ancient compiler impelements, not the "official" language of the time. But the main point of my answer remains: use a modern(ish) compiler for a modern(ish) language, if you want help from modern(ish) programmers.

Comment: Yes.  I'm not a fan of using the very latest features of the newest compiler (in general), but this feature was introduced with user overloading of `operator new` and `operator delete`, about 15 years ago.  (And in our field, 15 years is an eternity.)