# Destuctors and vector

Tags: c++, oop

I was thinking about this question for a while. When I tried to find answers on some websites, I found nothing. So the question is: if we have a vector of classes and we use a destructor of class, will it clear his position in the vector or we need to erase it ourselves?

```
class MyClass{
  ...
};

std::vector<MyClass> myClasses(2);
myClasses[0].~MyClass();
```

Comment: You need to remove it yourself.

Comment: You should not call the destructor manually. Removing an object from a vector will delete it, so it will be called automatically. If call it yourself, it will end up being called twice, which is not good.

Comment: There are very, very rare cases when you call the destructor of a class explicitly. This one is not the case! Rule of thumb, you **never** call the destructor explicitly!

Comment: To close-voter: Where is the typo? Or the non-reproducible problem? OP, is a new contributor to the community, please be mindful. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *not* call the destructor manually. When you call [`std::vector::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/), the destructor of the object will be called automatically, as @HolyBlackCat commented.

By calling the destructor manually, you'll end up being called twice, which is [not good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884168/destructor-being-called-twice-when-being-explicitly-invoked), so remember:

> **The solution is to never manually call your destructor.**

Just call:

```
myClasses.erase(myClasses.begin() + 0);
```

which will remove the first object of the vector, resulting in its destructor being called automatically.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that erase() calls the destructor automaticaly, thank you very much