# syntax error in case 'remove' when decrementing

Tags: php, case

I get a syntax error on the case "remove". I've been trying to fix it but I can't figure it out.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it?Thanks

The code is for a online shop shopping cart

```
switch($action)
{
    case "add":
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]++;
    else
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]=1;
break;

case "remove":
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))
    (
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]--; (ERROR HERE)
        if ($_SESSION['cart'][$id]==0)
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
    )
break;

case "empty":
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
break;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using parenthesis instead of brackets for your IF statement:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))
( <-- HERE
    $_SESSION['cart'][$id]--; (ERROR HERE)
    if ($_SESSION['cart'][$id]==0)
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
) <-- HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace `(` and `)` with `{` and `}`

Corrected code:

```
case "remove":
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]--; (ERROR HERE)
        if ($_SESSION['cart'][$id]==0)
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
    }
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

// Syntactical Errors, Find the corrected code!!

```
  switch($action)
  {
case "add":
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]++;
    }
    else {
          $_SESSION['cart'][$id]=1;
     }
    break;

case "remove":
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$id]--; //(ERROR HERE)
        }
        if ($_SESSION['cart'][$id]==0) {
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
        }
    break;

case "empty":
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
    break;

  }
```

Comment: Please don't promote writing `if` statements without braces around the body.

Comment: @Barmar : Thanks for the tip! Can you please let me know what is the harm if i dont use bracket for single line statement after if ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193170/whats-the-purpose-of-using-for-a-single-line