# The pointer could be used after delete?

Tags: c++, pointers

The question is to remove duplicates from sorted list  and the code is :

```
 /**
     * Definition for singly-linked list.
     * struct ListNode {
     *     int val;
     *     ListNode *next;
     *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
     * };
     */
    class Solution {
    public:
        ListNode* deleteDuplicates(ListNode* head) {
            if (head == NULL) return NULL;
            for (ListNode* prev = head, *cur = head->next; cur; cur = cur->next)
            {
                if (prev->val == cur->val)
                {
                    prev->next = cur ->next;
                    delete cur;
                }
                else
                {
                    prev = cur;
                }
            }
            return head;
        }
    };
```

The code is right ,My puzzle is :

the pointer "cur" , after "delete" , use" cur" and" cur = cur->next" in "for". Why is it OK?

**Sorry to trouble, The leetcode give AC to the code , so I doubt myself**, **Thanks to the answers.**

Comment: No, using a pointer after it was deleted is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I can also use it find the next? It means after delete cur->next is also pointer to the next node?

Comment: @Fanl As mentioned it's UB, regardless what you observe. You can't rely your code behaves in this way.

Comment: Among the things allowed by undefined behavior is "trick you into thinking you have a well-defined program, only to do something disastrous later on".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clarification first: a pointer is something that *points* to a memory area.

If you call `delete` on a pointer you're going to free whatever that pointer pointed to, but you **will not destroy the pointer itself**. You can reuse that pointer, but dereferencing it again after it has been deleted it's **undefined behavior** since nothing guarantees the memory it used to point to will still be available to you.

Your code causes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since after

```
delete cur;
```

you dereference that pointer with `cur = cur->next`. You have no guarantees that `cur` still points to a valid memory area where `next` has an actual meaning as an address.

A correct version of your code would be the following:

```
ListNode* deleteDuplicates(ListNode* head) {
  if (head == NULL) return NULL;
  for (ListNode* prev = head, *cur = head->next; prev->next; cur = prev->next)
  {
    if (prev->val == cur->val)
    {
      prev->next = cur->next;
      delete cur;
    }
    else
    {
      prev = cur;
    }
  }
  return head;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b574874f8fb3876)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not OK. It's just [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), anything is possible. In this case, the content the pointer point to happens not be cleared only, but you can't and shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

The function has undefined behaviour. You may not access an object after its deletion.

So this loop

```
        for (ListNode* prev = head, *cur = head->next; cur; cur = cur->next)
        {
            if (prev->val == cur->val)
            {
                prev->next = cur ->next;
                delete cur;
            }
        //...
```

is wrong.

The function can be defined the following way

```
ListNode* deleteDuplicates( ListNode *head ) 
{
    if ( head )
    {        
        for ( ListNode *current = head; current->next; )
        {
            if ( current->val == current->next->val )
            {
                ListNode *tmp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                delete tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }            
        }
    }        

    return head;
}
```

Comment: thanks , it give AC to me, as a new learner I puzzled . I should trust myself

Answer (score 0):

A `deleted` pointer could point anywhere. It is an undefined behaviour. It is a good practice to point the pointer `NULL` after deletion. It will explicitly make sure that you won't misuse the pointer instead crash with null pointer exception. I would change your code like this:-

```
            if (curr!=NULL && prev->val == cur->val)
            {
                prev->next = cur ->next;
                delete cur;
                cur = NULL;
            }
```

**EDIT**: I just checked that after delete you are accessing next with

```
cut = cur->next;
```

In your case it could work as you are executing your code with fixed data and the memory pointed by pointer `cur` was not overwritten. However in fairly complex program, there is good chance of `cur` being something else and `cur->next` could take you anywhere in the universe (in most cases segmentation error if using non flat memory architecture). But it is an unintended state. Thus making it `NULL` will definitely give you error. **Its better to exit with an exception rather than doing something unexpected.**

Comment: Not everybody agrees it is wise to set a pointer to NULL after deletion. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12194183/33499) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12196704/33499). And remember even if this could work in this simple situation; What if you use a version of `delete` which clears all memory? Some compilers do such things if you switch to debug mode.

Comment: @Wimmel I read the links and found that there are programmers supporting both the practices as you could see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704466/why-doesnt-delete-set-the-pointer-to-null. Basically if your code is clean enough then no worries, but if you are not sure about accessing your dangling pointer then I believe its better to get an null pointer exception. Imagine an OS like VxWorks with no memory protection. With a dangling pointer one could overwrite OS memory area also.

Answer (score 0):

The code is definitely NOT OK. The code is broken. Doing `cur = cur->next` after deleting the object pointed by `cur` is undefined behavior.