# Why I don't need brackets for loop and if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, brackets

I don't understand why I don't need brackets in this case

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    if (num[i] < min) 
        min = num[i];
```

And why I need brackets in this case

```
int num[10], min;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "enter 10 numbers" << endl;
        cin >> num[i];
}
```

Comment: Better you keep them. The syntax without is just error prone.

Comment: The grammar allows it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but it is used a lot in programming books, Is there an advantage of that syntax anyway?

Comment: @Ayxan As mentioned, it's error prone, e.g. if statements are added later on and the maintainer forgets to add the braces.

Answer (score 17):

Both the `for` and the `if` have to be followed by a "statement". A "statement" can be a simple statement, like `min = num[i];`, a more complicated one like `if (num[i] < min) min = num[i];` or it can be a compound statement (i.e., zero or more simple statements enclosed in curly braces), like `{ std::cout << "enter 10 numbers\n"; std::cin >> num[i]; }`

Some people think that cluttering simple statements with syntactically redundant curly braces is good style. Others don't.

Answer (score 13):

**Because you don't.**

They are optional. That is just how it is.

If you don't use braces to group multiple statements into one, then only the first statement following the `for` or `if` preamble is considered part of that construct. (But this rule is transitive, so your assignment is part of your `if` is part of your `for`!)

It is important to note that *indentation has no effect*.

Many people believe<sup>[citation needed]</sup> that you should *always* use braces, for clarity.

Comment: Other people think that obfuscation can be fun ;-)
http://www.ioccc.org/

Answer (score 7):

Single statement if and for loops do not need curly braces. Here is a discussion of why curly braces are a good practice even for single statements.

[What's the purpose of using braces (i.e. {}) for a single-line if or loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193170/whats-the-purpose-of-using-braces-i-e-for-a-single-line-if-or-loop)

Comment: Single line? `op1; op2;` is that a single line?

Comment: FSVO "line", yes.

Comment: I think you should change your wording, "single line" is misleading

Comment: What is a better wording than single line? Single line of execution?

Comment: Statement. Inexperienced developer may think that putting multiple statements in one line of code (textually) will make them "single line"

Comment: Fixed. Thank you @Slava!

Answer (score 6):

A for loop has the syntax

```
for (init, condition, post) statement;
```

Now this means that any single statement right after the `for(...)` will be the body and will be what is ran for the loop.

Then we have the if statement which has the syntax of

```
if(condition) statement;
```

So we can see that the whole if

```
if (num[i] < min) 
    min = num[i];
```

Is just a single statement which is all you need for the for loop.

The reason we use {} when we have more than one line in a loop or condition is to let us use multi-statement loops/conditions as the whole block is treated as a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

1. In case of FOR loop: You don't have to use braces but according to my knowledge you should. First of all it increases code readability, it can save you form useless debugging the code. For future readers Oracle's code conventions clearly says that you should always use braces.
2. In case of IF statements: For a single statement you don't have to use braces, but if you want to group more than one statement inside the IF block then you have to use curely braces.

I hope that my opinion will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Lightness Races in Orbit summed it up perfectly - it's just a matter of good practice. A lot of programmers probably don't use brackets in that manner out of sheer laziness (it IS optional, after all).

If you want code that's easy to read, and even more importantly easy to debug, then you should get in the habit of using brackets after EVERY for loop and if statement.

It'll probably get tedious after a while, but like I said - it's just a matter of good practice.

Answer (score 1):

We basically use brackets to keep code clean and as much as i know about coding the compiler is not so smart so if you have multiple statements in a loop or in an if condition then we use brackets (curly braces {}) just to let the compiler know that every statement in the braces are a part of the loop or a part of the if statement.

Comment: The compiler is extremely smart, but it cannot read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to go without braces, as illustrated by the responses.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) /*For-loop only has one executable
                              *statement in its scope, the if-statement, 
                              *so doesn't need braces.*/
    if (num[i] < min) /*If-statement contains only one executable
                       *statement its scope, so doesn't need braces*/
        min = num[i]; //One line of code to execute.
```

Stick with braces, it'll make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Loop without bracket can easily get messed up, especially when programmers get tired.

But the compiler can understand it.

Example 1: A complete line that ends with `;` and also immediately follows a for statement belongs to the scope of the for statement. But the line after it won't. Just try to compile it and run it.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        std::cout << "in scope of for" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "out of scope of for" << std::endl;
}
```

Example 2: Same for the `if` statement

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void){
    if (1 == 1)
        std::cout << "in scope of if" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "out of scope of if" << std::endl;
}
```

Example 3:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void){
    int num[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int min = num[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            if (num[i] < min) //this if belong to the for above
                min = num[i]; //this line belong to `if` above
                              //so this line also belong to the `for`
                              //as the `for` own the `if`
}
```

Comment: `iosteram`? Talk about getting tired! And this is C++; no need for `void` in empty parameter lists.