# How to print (output) multiple lines from a loop?

Tags: for-loop

I would like to know how to output multiple lines from a for loop.
For example, if I want to input a number of subsequent lines N and then another numbers. I am trying to output the inputs that I provided below, but whenever I do this it keeps returning only the last digits and not everything I entered.

This is what I know so far.

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N, M, num;
    cin >> N;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
          cin >> M;
          for (int k = 0; k < M; k++)
            cout << M << endl;
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Input:

2 (This is for N)
1 2 3
4 5 6

or

3
10 20 30
50 100 500
1000 5 0

---------

Output:

1 2 3
4 5 6

10 20 30
50 100 500
1000 5 0
```

Comment: I think you need braces around the bodies of the for loop. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579686/why-i-dont-need-brackets-for-loop-and-if-statement

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to added here. Still, it doesn't fix my issue. I keeps returning only one digit from the three digits I entered (if I entered 2 3 4 it returns 2 2 2).

Comment: Could you add them to your question? link to [edit]

Comment: There it is. So, I noticed that when I enter the number of lines which is 2 then the digits 1 2 3 it returns the 3 (three times) only instead of 1 2 3.

Comment: Do you have braces on the inner loops? The second one is likely the problem

Comment: I am getting closer. Look at the updated code. Now it is returning the numbers I entered, however, it returns it the wrong way. Now when I enter 1 2 3, it returns 1 2 2 3 3 3.  want only 1 2 3