# C++ Single line If-Else within Loop

Tags: c++, loops, conditional-statements, braces

I read [Why I don't need brackets for loop and if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579686/), but I don't have enough reputation points to reply with a follow-up question.

I know it's bad practice, but I have been challenged to minimise the lines of code I use.

Can you do this in any version of C++?

```
a_loop()
    if ( condition ) statement else statement
```

i.e. does the if/else block count as one "statement"?

Similarly, does if/else if.../else count as one "statement"? Though doing so would become totally unreadable.

The post I mentioned above, only says things like:

```
a_loop()
    if(condition_1) statement_a; // is allowed.
```

Comment: Did you simply try out yourself?

Comment: yup. It worked. It's worth keeping up in case someone else finds this relevant.

Comment: ***I read this, but I don't have enough [SO] rank points to reply with a follow-up question*** You are never supposed to add a follow-up question to some other question. Instead you are supposed to add your own question and link to the previous question if needed.

Comment: I am aware of this. The actual code was a longer expression, but for simplicity, I wrote this. Question modified to most general form.

Comment: @SanjitRaman just to add some more seemingly weird: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work 

Comment: @drescherjm that is what I did right? Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes what you did by asking a new question is correct.

Comment: I deleted my comment about reducing to 2 lines because the answer from @ShivCK is better. It's morning here and I obviously need more coffee..

Comment: c++ syntax generally doesn't care about whitespace or newlines at all. Preprocessor directives and includes would be an exception, a few more might exist. But you should be able to write a whole program with classes and all on just one line if you want.

Comment: Yes I am aware, thank you. Our guidelines are vague, but just wanted to know whether I could make this simplification.

Comment: Reducing the number of lines is never a good challenge:
It does not make the code easier to read/write or shorter and ... you can always just cram everything into a single line - nothing prevents you from doing so. And for the if/else you can always have the {} inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, syntactically you can do that.

if/else block is a *selection-statement*, which is a kind of statement.

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 6.4 Selection statements says:

> ```
> selection-statement:
>     if ( condition ) statement
>     if ( condition ) statement else statement
>     switch ( condition ) statement
> ```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ternary operator` instead of `if...else`

```
while(true) return condition_1 ? a : b;
```

`while` seems redundant here if the value of its argument is always `true` so you can simply write

```
return condition_1 ? a : b;
```