# A "misplaced else" error in this C++ program

Tags: c++, if-statement, turbo-c++

I cannot seem to fix the "misplaced else" error in the code below.  This code should collect and compute for term grades and give remarks depending on the score.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char name[20];
    int exam, q1, q2, q3, ass, sw, att, avgq, CS, TG;
    clrscr();
    printf("Name: ");
    gets(name);
    printf("\nExam: ");
    scanf("%d", &exam);
    printf("\nQuiz #1: ");
    scanf("%d", &q1);
    printf("\nQuiz #2: );
    scanf("%d", &q2);
    printf("\nQuiz #3: ");
    scanf("%d", &q3);
    printf("\nAssignment: ");
    scanf("%d", &ass);
    printf("\nSeatwotk: ");
    scanf("%d", &sw);
    printf("\nAttendance: ");
    scanf("%d", &att);
    CS = (0.4*ass) + (0.4*sw) + (0.2*att);  // class standing //
    avgq = (q1 + q2 + q3)/3;  // Average quiz //
    TG = (0.4*exam) + (0.3*avgq) + (0.3*CS);  // Term grade //
    if(TG >= 90)
       printf("Term Grade: %d", TG);
       printf("Remarks: EXCELLENT");
    else if (TG>=80 && TG<=89)
       printf("Term Grade: %d", TG);
       printf("Remarks: SATISFACTORY");
    else if (TG>=76 && TG<=79)
       printf("Term Grade: %d", TG);
       printf("Remarks: GOOD");
    else if (TG == 75)
       printf("Term Grade: %d", TG);
       printf("Remarks: PASSING");
    else if (TG<74)
       printf("Term Grade: %d", TG);
       printf("Remarks: FAILED");
    else
       printf("Invalid Input.  Try again");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to add braces `{}` for each of your `if` blocks. Your code is horribly broken without them. C++ doesn't scope based on indentation like Python. ***NEVER OMIT CURLY BRACES FROM YOUR CODE.***

Comment: You 're on c++ not python, use curly brackets.

Comment: This is a mega duplicate. What is the canonical question?

Comment: A candidate (2013—though not canonical (there must be some from 2008 or 2009)): *[Why do I get a compiling error that says error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587875/)*

Comment: Related (about mitigation. Canonical): *[What's the purpose of using braces (i.e. {}) for a single-line if or loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193170/)*

Answer (score 1):

Uh oh! Noob alert! Just kidding; we all have to start somewhere ;)

So do not worry, fair maiden! The problem lies here:

When you declare an *if* statement, you must encompass the body of the *if* statement with curly braces. If you don't do that, only the first line below the *if* statement will be run. Here's an example:

```
// Here, both do something 1 and do something 2 are being run in the 'if' statement
if (something) {
    do something 1;
    do something 2;
}

// Here, only do something 1 will get run inside the 'if' statement
if (something)
    do something 1;
    do something 2;
```

So back to your problem. You **must** put curly braces {} around the code in an *if* statement if the *if* statement body consists of more than one line.

```
if (something)
    do something 1;
    do something 2;
else
    do something 3;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (something)
    do something 1;
do something 2;
else do something 3;
```

That is why your *else* statement throws an error. Each *else* must have an *if* before it.

Comment: Thanks this worked!  It wasn't mentioned in class because we didn't have to use more than one statement in one if statement.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear! Click the checkmark button and the up-arrow of this question if it helped you out ;)

Comment: @MonCabrera Click the check mark button; it'd help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't use indentation to determine the ends of statements. You need braces if you want more than one statement.

Instead of:

```
if (a)
  b;
  c;
else
  d;
```

Use:

```
if (a) {
  b;
  c;
} else {
  d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 line under an if or else, they must be contained in curly braces, like this:

```
if(TG>=90)
{
   printf("Term Grade: %d",TG);
   printf("Remarks: EXCELLENT");
}
else if (TG>=80 && TG<=89)
{
   printf("Term Grade: %d",TG);
   printf("Remarks: SATISFACTORY");
}
```