# Why in programming are the braces not arranged next to the text they enclose?

Tags: coding-style, braces

([12193170](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193170/whats-the-purpose-of-using-braces-i-e-for-a-single-line-if-or-loop): **not** the same question  (or not the right answers for that matter...))

So basically why this:

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    } 
}
```

And not this:

```
public class HelloWorld 
{public static void main(String[] args) 
{System.out.println("Hello World");}}`
```

Comment: What if there's more than one statement? And this will at best be opinion based.

Comment: Your code will be completly unreadable if there if there where a couple if-statements inside (at least for other people then Emdosis).

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for using a particular formatting ( position braces and *indentation*) is for **visibility**.

Your example is too simple and you could argue that both versions are easy to read (although first version look simpler to me). When you have hundreds of lines of code, you really appreciate having your code properly formatted.

But you could use other formatting styles if you prefer, for example:

```
public class HelloWorld 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
     System.out.println("Hello World");
   } 
}
```