# C/C++ no curly brace after if/for, how to lint it out?

Tags: c++, c, cppcheck

Is there way to get rid or find by linting (or maybe `sed`ing/`regexp`ing) these nasty situations when your have just one line of code after if/for statement, without curly braces? Like this one:

```c
if(condition)
    return;
```

For reference why would I want to get rid of that - there are lots of reasons given in this thread:

[What's the purpose of using braces (i.e. {}) for a single-line if or loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193170/whats-the-purpose-of-using-braces-i-e-for-a-single-line-if-or-loop)

I maintain some legacy code, and deal with some not-really-finished code from other people, and from time to time stumble on situation when this code-style works like a trip wire when debugging:

```c
if(condition_for_early_return)
    LOG("Im here")   // surprise surprise, I just broke control logic
    return;
```

Also, I've seen code like that:

```c
if(condition)
<tabs>   do_smth();
<spaces> do_smth_else();
```

Of course `if` contains only first `do_smth()`, compiler is not confused. But because the `do_` functions are visually aligned, I wonder - is this intended behaviour or is it a bug that was never found in this legacy code.

I know `cppcheck` does not catch these situation - already tried that.
Do you have any way of finding these traps automatically?

Comment: *But because the do_ functions are visually alligned*  **ANOTHER** reason to never use tabs for indentation:  obfuscation of actual intent.

Answer (score 12):

GCC has:

*-Wmisleading-indentation (C and C++ only)*

> Warn when the indentation of the code does not reflect the block
> structure. Specifically, a warning is issued for if, else, while, and
> for clauses with a guarded statement that does not use braces,
> followed by an unguarded statement with the same indentation.
>
> In the following example, the call to “bar” is misleadingly indented
> as if it were guarded by the “if” conditional.

```
  if (some_condition ())
    foo ();
    bar ();  /* Gotcha: this is not guarded by the "if".  */
```

> In the case of mixed tabs and spaces, the warning uses the *-ftabstop=*
> option to determine if the statements line up (defaulting to 8).
>
> The warning is not issued for code involving multiline preprocessor
> logic such as the following example.

```
  if (flagA)
    foo (0);
#if SOME_CONDITION_THAT_DOES_NOT_HOLD
  if (flagB)
#endif
    foo (1);
```

> The warning is not issued after a #line directive, since this
> typically indicates autogenerated code, and no assumptions can be made
> about the layout of the file that the directive references.

Note that this warning is enabled by *-Wall* in C and C++.

---

Alternatively, clang-format provides:

*-InsertBraces (Boolean) clang-format 15*

> Insert braces after control statements (if, else, for, do, and while)
> in C++ unless the control statements are inside macro definitions or
> the braces would enclose preprocessor directives.

But also issues a warning:

> Setting this option to true could lead to incorrect code formatting
> due to clang-format’s lack of complete semantic information. As such,
> extra care should be taken to review code changes made by this option.

Answer (score 4):

A quick google showed that SonarSource's linter has a rule for this: https://rules.sonarsource.com/cpp/RSPEC-121

I believe there's a way to use this tool for free to some extent, so it should work.

Alternatively, clang-format supports the option to just add them since v15: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#insertbraces

Answer (score 2):

Clang-tidy actually has a check for that, and if I remember correctly, it can also fix things automatically for you (you should of course then manually go through all the changes and make sure they're correct)