# A piece of C++ code get "invalid pointer" error

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *p = new int[2];
    p[0] = 1;
    p[1] = 2;
    cout << *p++ << endl;
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

It can be compiled, but got a runtime error "free(): invalid pointer", followed by a memory map.

operating system ubuntu 10.10
compiler: g++ 4.4.3

Answer (score 6):

You need to call the array-version of `delete`:

```
delete[] p;
```

**EDIT**: However, your real problem is that you're incrementing `p`.
The `delete` operators only work on the original pointers that were allocated.

Comment: a side note it is very important if you do any serious coding to also set p = NULL; after it is deleted

Comment: @pyCthon It is not very important, and not a prerequisite to any kind of coding. [A discussion on the matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931126/is-it-good-practice-to-null-a-pointer-after-deleting-it).

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `delete` must use the same pointer returned by your call to `new`.

In your code, you increment `p` with `*p++`, which due to operator precedence is interpreted as `*(p++)`.  Due to this, you are providing `delete` a pointer that the memory manager has never heard of.

Additionally, you should use `delete[]` to match a call to `new[]`.

That being said, here is a guess of what you may have intended:

```
int *p = new int[2];
p[0] = 1;
p[1] = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    cout << p[i] << endl;
delete[] p;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look a the code:

```
int *p1 = new int;
int *p2 = new int[2];

int *p3 = p1;
int *p1 = p2;

delete p3;
delete[] p1;
```

Pointers `p1` and `p2` have the same representation and the same set of allowed operations. For the compiler they are both `int*`.

Althougth the objects that they are pointing at are significantly different. The object from `new int[2]` at hegative offset has a header that contains the number of items in the array.

Working with array object is the same as if it were a scalar object. Only when this object is released, it is necessary to tell the compiler what sort of object is it. A simple object or an array. This is known source of bugs and confusion. Neverthless the language was defined in this way decades ago and we cannot change this.

It is also important to `delete` exactly the same pointer that was returned with `new`. This rule applies both to simple `new` and `new[]`.