# How to set pointer to an int array to NULL in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

For a pointer to an int, I can do -

```
int *p = new int;
*p = 10;

delete p; // Step 1: Memory Freed
p = 0; // Step 2: Pointer set to NULL
```

Now, if I have a pointer to an int array -

```
int *p = new int[10];
p[1] = 1;
p[5] = 5;
delete[] p; // Step 1: Memory freed corresponding to whole array
```

Now, how to achieve 'Step 2' for this case?

Comment: It's better to use nullptr when you are working with pointers. (It's not about downvotes, just a small guideline)

Comment: Probably downvotes are here, because your title of the question contradicts your code. You don't have an array of pointers. You have a normal array of int. And a pointer, which points to the first element of this array.

Comment: @IvanGusev And `NULL` if he doesn't have access to C++11 (but if he does, `nullptr` is far superior).

Comment: With new edits, I think the answer is obvious. p is just a pointer, so you could do the same as in first snippet.
But please be aware, that sometimes setting a pointer to null may lead to hiding mistakes. E.g. if in your code you accidentally delete the same pointer twice - it's an indication that there are flaws in you code and you might forgot to delete some another pointer. In general second delete will cause a crash, so you will be aware of it. But if you set pointer as null, "delete 0" will just do nothing and you wouldn't know about the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have an array of `int` pointers. You just have an array of `int`. Since you only have one pointer, `p`, you can just do the same thing as you did previously:

```
p = 0; // or nullptr, preferably
```

If you *did* have an array of `int` pointers, you will probably have allocated them in a loop. In the same way, you can deallocate them and set them to `0` in a loop:

```
int* array[10];
for (auto& p : array) {
  p = new int;
}

// Some time later...

for (auto& p : array) {
  delete p;
  p = 0;
}
```

Do consider [whether you need to set your pointers to null after `delete`ing them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1931126/150634).