# Delete a pointer,make it NULL or nothing?

Tags: c++, null, delete-operator

talking about C++.
Let's say I have an array of pointers to objects.In position Array[6] for example,I want to replace the object pointed by, with another of the same type.
Which is the wisest way?

1.

```
delete Array[6];
Array[6]=new Object(...);
```

2.

```
Array[6]=NULL;
Array[6]=new Object(...);
```

3.

```
Array[6]=new Object(...);
```

Or something else I'm missing.Waiting for advice,thank you!!

EDIT: 
question:
Do you want to delete the object pointed to by Array[6]? If so, do delete Array[6];. If not, don't delete Array[6];. I'm not sure what there is to be confused about there.

answer: 
Yes,it's what you've mentioned that I want. I want the object pointed by Array[6] to "disappear" and make a new one there. 
My other problem: I want to delete some objects of the Array in a function, but in another I want to access them so I have to check.
Which will be my check?
Maybe: 
  if (Array[i]==NULL){..} or is it wrong  since I have not "NULLed" it?

Comment: delete it, other wise memory leak

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it good practice to NULL a pointer after deleting it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931126/is-it-good-practice-to-null-a-pointer-after-deleting-it)

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between `delete` and assigning `NULL` to a pointer variable. I suggest you educate about that difference.

Comment: @datenwolf isnt that the point of the question

Comment: After deleting,i guess I have destroyed the Object pointed to by Array[6],so now Array[6] can't be accessed,right?                                                                                             What should I check then,so as not to access a deleted position on my Array?

Comment: Do you want to delete the object pointed to by `Array[6]`? If so, do `delete Array[6];`. If not, don't `delete Array[6];`. I'm not sure what there is to be confused about there.

Comment: Yes,it's what you've mentioned that I want. I want the object pointed by Array[6] to "disappear" and make a new one there.

Comment: Do you really need to destroy the object and make a new one? Can't you just change the value of the object? Does the object not support `operator=`? Why not `*(Array[6]) = ...;` or `*(Array[6]) = Object(...);`?

Comment: @pm100: I think OP may still have problems grasping that a pointer is just a pointer and that by `delete Array[6]` it's not `Array[6]` that gets destroyed, but the object `Array[6]` is pointing to. `Array[6]` of course still can be accessed, but the pointer it holds is then invalid.

Comment: I know that the object gets destroyed and not the Array[6].But I search for a way afterwards to check if Array[6] is pointing to an existing object or a deleted one.(NULL) How I will achieve that?

Comment: Can anyone help me on that? How will I make sure with a statement(?) that I will not try to access a deleted memory and end with an undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 and 3 are likely to cause memory leaks. As such I would suggest 1, or use array of smart pointers and reset them with new object.

Comment: we dont know they have leaks, it depends if the array is the only place where that old pointer was stored. Probably but not 100%

Comment: @pm100 based on the title the OP wants to reset the pointers and she/he wonders which one of the 3 methods renders best. As such my argument holds.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is very different. The other 2 are basically the same (but with more or less typing)

Do #1 if the array is the owner of the object, ie you need to free the memory. Otherwise do #2 or 3

And anyway use std::vector and std::shared_ptr

If feels like you come from languages that do magic with references (like c# or Java) where assugining null to a pointer actually does someting. Not so in c++ (unless you use smart pointers and containers as I said before)