# Binary Search Tree Destructor issue

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, destructor

I am currently making a code a class code for binary search tree but I am getting an error in the destructor for my BST class. This is my relevant part of code:

Node Struct:

```
struct Node{
    int key;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};
```

Function to Create new node:

```
Node* BST::CreateNode(int key){
    Node* temp_node = new Node();
    temp_node->key = key;
    temp_node->left = nullptr;
    temp_node->right = nullptr;
    return temp_node;
}
```

Assignment Operator:

```
BST& BST::operator=(const BST& cpy_bst){
    if (this != &cpy_bst){
        Node* cpy_root = cpy_bst.root;
        this->root=assgRec(cpy_root, this->root);
    }
    return *this;
}

 Node* BST::assgRec(Node* src_root, Node* dest_root){
    if (src_root != nullptr){
        dest_root = CreateNode(src_root->key);
        dest_root->left=assgRec(src_root->left, dest_root->left);
        dest_root->right=assgRec(src_root->right, dest_root->right);
    }
    return src_root;
}
```

Destructor:

```
BST::~BST(){

    DestroyNode(root);
}

 void BST::DestroyNode(Node* r){
        if (r != nullptr){
            DestroyNode(r->left);
            DestroyNode(r->right);
            delete r;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that after I have used the assignment in main function, like:

BST bin_tree2=bin_tree1;

The destructor is called but after it deletes the data in bin_tree1, all values that were placed in bin_tree2 have some junk values in them and I get an error on that part. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hello! This:   Unhandled exception at 0x00FA49DC in DSAssg5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDE1.

Comment: Please provide the code for your Node class.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: `r = nullptr` what are you trying to do?

Comment: @curiousguy I am setting the value of r back to null after de-allocating it

Comment: @curiousguy It's a good practice to do it. It is not wrong! Although, in this case it's not necessary to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931126/is-it-good-practice-to-null-a-pointer-after-deleting-it

Comment: @Hamza750 any luck?

Comment: Sorry no, it won't stop deep copy:((. I am trying though

Comment: You are setting to null a pointer that is about to go out of scope. You are also passing a null pointer to a function... your code makes no sense.

Comment: `Node* cpy_root = nullptr; assgRec(cpy_root, this->root);` is an interesting choice, since your `assgRec()` only does anything if the first parameter _isn't_ `nullptr`.

Comment: @JustinTime yes that was an issue I just noticed but I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are copying pointers and accessing them after memory has been deallocated.

The problem seems not to be with the keys as I said earlier but with the nodes that seem to be improperly constructed in the BST::assgRec function.

Comment: It's exactly that problem but how exactly am I getting it? As far as I know, I'm only copying the value of src_root's key to dest_root's key.