# Does free(ptr) where ptr is NULL corrupt memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, null, free

Theoretically I can say that

```
free(ptr);
free(ptr);
```

is a memory corruption since we are freeing the memory which has already been freed.

But what if

```
free(ptr);
ptr=NULL;
free(ptr);
```

As the OS will behave in an undefined manner I cannot get an actual theoretical analysis for this about what's happening.
Whatever I am doing, is this memory corruption or not?

Is freeing a NULL pointer valid?

Comment: not sure about C free standard, but in C++ delete(NULL) is perfectly valid, so I guess free(NULL) should also be.

Comment: @Pryank: `delete NULL` is not valid in C++. delete can be applied to null-pointer values of concrete type, but not to `NULL`. `delete (int*) NULL` is legal, but not `delete NULL`.

Comment: so it means if a pointer is pointing to NULL free does not perform anything.does that mean!!!!!! every time in our coding if want to free a memory can simply replace a free(ptr) with ptr=NULL?

Comment: No. If `ptr` points to memory, and you don't call `free` on it, then the memory will leak. Setting it to `NULL` just loses your handle on the memory, and leaks. If the `ptr` *happens to be `NULL`*, calling `free` is a no-operations.

Comment: @benjamin: Huh? What made you to conclude that you can replace `free(ptr)` with `ptr = NULL`. No one said anything like that.

Comment: @benjamin: free does not free the variable passed in, it frees a __block of memory__ previously allocated and referenced by the pointer value in the passed-in value.  So, ptr is not being freed, the block pointed to by ptr is being freed.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879550/should-one-really-set-pointers-to-null-after-freeing-them

Comment: @Vijay free() deals with the right of a pointer variable to use memory (that variable's ownership of a block of memory), NOT what values are stored in/at that memory location.
`free( someIntPointer )` ===> tellOperatingSystemThat_`someIntPointer`_noLongerHasRightsToReadNorWrite_sizeOfInteger_AmountOfMemory.
`ptr = NULL;` means that the pointer is pointing to memory address 0x00000000 (there may be more hex 0s added to the end of that number, but it still has memory address 0). This statement is NOT saying what data lies at that address, nor how many bytes will be stored there (since no type)

Answer (score 267, accepted):

> 7.20.3.2 The `free` function
>
> Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h> 
> void free(void *ptr);
> ```
>
> Description
>
> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made 
>   available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs.

See [ISO-IEC 9899](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf).

That being said, when looking at different codebases in the wild, you'll notice people sometimes do:

```
if (ptr)
  free(ptr);
```

This is because some C runtimes (I for sure remember it was the case on PalmOS) would crash when freeing a `NULL` pointer.

But nowadays, I believe it's safe to assume `free(NULL)` is a nop as per instructed by the standard.

Comment: so it means if a pointer is pointing to NULL free does not perform anything.does that mean!!!!!! every time in our coding if want to free a memory can simply replace a free(ptr) with ptr=NULL?

Comment: No, ptr=NULL is no way a replacement for free(ptr), both are completely different

Comment: NO, it means `free(ptr)` where `ptr` is null has no side effects. But in any case, every memory allocated using `malloc()` or `calloc()` must be  released afterwards using `free()`

Comment: ptr=NULL ensures that even if you accidently call free(ptr) your program won't segfault.

Comment: You don't need to ask your question multiple times. Edit your question post and append the information you want.

Comment: Please note that although the C standard says it is a no-op, that doesn't mean that every C-library handles it like that. I've seen crashes for free(NULL), so it's best to avoid calling the free in the first place.

Comment: @Derick avoid calling free? How do you free your memory then?

Comment: @WereWolfBoy he means avoid `free(NULL)` by testing the pointer against `NULL` before calling `free()`

Comment: @GregoryPakosz ah, that makes sense. Sorry :D

Answer (score 34):

All standards compliant versions of the C library treat free(NULL) as a no-op.

That said, at one time there were some versions of free that would crash on free(NULL) which is why you may see some defensive programming techniques recommend:

```
if (ptr != NULL)
    free(ptr);
```

Comment: -1 [citation needed]. Changing code-style because of some theory of an archaic hearsay implementation is a bad idea.

Comment: @Tomas - I never recommended changing style, I simply explained why you may still see this recommendation in some styles.

Comment: @Tomas 3BSD (http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-patches/2006-October/031544.html) and PalmOS for two (2nd hand for both).

Comment: @Tomas: the problem was in things like Version 7 Unix.  When I was learning, free(xyz) where xyz == NULL was a recipe for instant disaster on the machine where I learned (ICL Perq running PNX, which was based on Version 7 Unix with some System III extras).  But I've not code that way for a long time.

Comment: Netware crashes on free-ing NULL too... (just debugged a crash on it...)

Comment: @Calmarius That's why they are discontinued? LOL

Comment: *"All standards compliant versions of the C library treat free(NULL) as a no-op"* - Some non-compliant ones also do. For example, glibc lacks the safer string functions from TR-24731, so it non-compliant; but it does allow you to free a `NULL` ptr and treat it like a nop. Drepper personally opposes the safer string functions so glibc will likely never be compliant.

Comment: Drepper hasn't been in charge of glibc since 2012.  However there are many people who agree with him regarding the (lack of) utility of the string functions in TR-24731.  Also C11 Annex K (TR-24731) is optional, so glibc is not non-compliant for omitting it.  Finally, there are serious proposals to remove Annex K from the next standard; see N1967 submitted to WG14.  Requiring free(NULL) to be a no-op was part of the first ANSI C 1989/ISO C 1990 standard so there's _no_ C runtime compliant with _any_ version of the C standard that doesn't support it.

Comment: @jww The bounds-checking interface added in C11 was always an optional feature. The compiler doesn't have to implement it and can still be compliant. Same thing as with the complex numbers lib, the thread lib and so on: they are optional.

Answer (score 15):

> If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.

says the documentation.

Comment: do u mean taht free will not perform anything?

Comment: benjamin, that's exactly what it means. What would you expect it to perform if it's aware of nullness of the argument?

Answer (score 13):

I remember working on PalmOS where `free(NULL)` crashed.

Comment: Interesting - that makes a second platform (after 3BSD) that crashes.

Comment: If I remember correctly, on Palm the C Standard Library didn't exist. Instead, there was a mostly unsupported header file that mapped standard library calls through to the Palm OS SDK. Lots of things acted unexpectedly. Crashing on `NULL` was one of the big running differences of the Palm toolbox compared to the standard library.

Comment: PalmOS was *freestanding* C implementation and therefore had no obligation to provide the standard C library.  Its analogue to `free` (`MemPtrFree`) was not standards compliant, and `free` was aliased to `MemPtrFree` as a (crude) attempt to provide a  standard-*like* API.

Answer (score 9):

```
free(ptr);
ptr=NULL;
free(ptr);/*This is perfectly safe */
```

You can safely delete a NULL pointer. No operation will be performed in that case.In other words  free() does nothing on a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 8):

Recomended usage:

```
free(ptr);
ptr = NULL;
```

See:

```
man free

     The free() function deallocates the memory allocation pointed to by ptr.
     If ptr is a NULL pointer, no operation is performed.
```

When you set the pointer to `NULL` after `free()` you can call `free()` on it again and no operation will be performed.

Comment: That also help to spot segfaults with a debugger. It is evident that segfault at p->do() with p=0 is someone using a freed pointer. Less evident when you see p=0xbfade12 in debugger :)

Answer (score 7):

`free(NULL)` is perfectly legal in C as well as `delete (void *)0` and `delete[] (void *)0` are legal in C++.

BTW, freeing memory twice usually causes some kind of runtime error, so it does not corrupt anything.

Comment: `delete 0` is not legal in C++. `delete` explicitly requires an expression of pointer type. It is legal to apply `delete` to a typed null-pointer value, but not to `0` (and not to `NULL`).

Comment: You cannot delete `void*` either :P Which destructors(s) should it run?

Comment: @GMan: You *can* delete `void *` as long as it is a null-pointer.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I forgot we're only dealing specifically with null.

Comment: usually does not corrupt anything, but is not guaranteed to. ASLR makes this rather unlikely, but still not impossible: ```buf1=malloc(X); free(buf1);buf2=malloc(X);free(buf1); ``` - here if you're unlucky, buf2 got the exact same address as buf1, and you accidentally freed buf1 twice, so on the 2nd free of buf1 you actually freed buf2 silently, without casuing any (immidate) error/crash/whatever. (but you'll still probably get a crash next time you try to use buf2 - and this scenario is very unlikely if you're running on ASLR)

Answer (score 4):

`free(ptr)` is save in C if `ptr` is `NULL`, however, what most people don't know is that `NULL` need not be equal to 0. I have a nice old-school example: On the C64, on address 0, there is an IO-Port. If you wrote a program in C accessing this port, you'd need a pointer whose value is 0. The corresponding C library would have to distinguish between 0 and `NULL` then.

Kind regards.

Comment: Interesting fact, caught me by surprise. Made me feel compelled to take a trip around NULL pointer questions/answers.

Comment: However you will never free this port.

Answer (score 1):

not memory corruption, but behavior depends on implementation.
By standard, it should be a legal code.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is safe nowadays, I always use the following macro to free pointers:

```c
#define FREE(ptr)      \ 
{                      \
    if ((ptr) != NULL) \
    {                  \
        free(ptr);     \
        (ptr) = NULL;  \
    }                  \
}
```

Answer (score -5):

ptr is pointing to some memory location, lets say 0x100.

When you free(ptr), basically you are allowing 0x100 to be used by memory manager to be used for other activity or process and in simple words it is deallocation of resources.

When you do ptr=NULL, you are making ptr point to new location(lets not worry about what NULL is). Doing this you lost track of the 0x100 memory data.This is what is memory leak.

So it is not advisable to use ptr=NULL on a valid ptr.

Instead you could do some safe check by using :

if(ptr != NULL)
{free(ptr);}

When you free(ptr) where ptr is already pointing to NULL, it performs no operation.So, its safe to do so.

Comment: But if the memory is already freed as in the question then the pointer is invalid and should be set to `NULL` so if it is freed again there will not be a double free error

Comment: Order matters. `free(ptr); ptr=NULL;` is *extremely* different from `ptr=NULL; free(ptr);`

The first deallocates the memory (variable gets its read/write rights to that chunk of memory revoked) and **then** removes any way of accessing that memory, which is completely safe and fine (as long as you never assign anything to `ptr` without *also* allocating new memory to `ptr` in the future).

The second removes any way of accessing that memory (`ptr=NULL;`), *then* tries to access it in order to revoke its rights (via `free(ptr)`)!