# C automatic variables

Tags: c, static

What happens if we free an automatic variable using `free()`?

What about in the following code: if `n` is `static` does it get automatically free'd after the last loop iteration, can we `free` it, or what?

```
for(count = 0; count < 5; count++) {  
    static int i += 1
}
```

Comment: Alright, now what about the static variable?

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337972/c-call-free-on-an-automatic-variable

Comment: @user3121023: Why guess? The standard says it exists during the entire execution of the program. You could legally take its address and use it after the loop, or even the containing function, has terminated; only the name `i` is local to the loop.

Comment: Your code fragment has no `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens if we free an automatic variable using `free()`?

It will invoke *undefined behavior*.

**Argument to `free` must be a pointer that was returned by memory allocation function** (`malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`). The argument may also be a null pointer, in which case the call of `free` has no effect.

Comment: It is also legal to free a null pointer, even if it was not returned by an allocation function. (C11 7.22.3.3:2)

Comment: @PascalCuoq; Yes true. Added that.

Answer (score 0):

If you `free()` an automatic variable the result is undefined.

`static` variables are cleaned up by the runtime.  There is no need to `free` them.

`free` is only used on a pointer that you allocated with `malloc/calloc`

Answer (score 0):

The **only** valid arguments to `free` are the result of a previous call to one of the `*alloc` functions (`malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`) or `NULL`.  That's it.

`auto` variables exist for the lifetime of their enclosing scope; attempting to call `free` on one will invoke undefined behavior (which *may* result in an access violation or a segfault).

`static` variables exist for the lifetime of the program, even if their visibliity is limited to a particular scope; the `i` in your `for` loop is allocated at program startup and held until the program terminates, but can only be accessed within the scope of the `for` loop.  As with `auto` variables, attempting to call `free` on a static variable will invoked undefined behavior, and will probably result in a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

The single argument to `free()` is a *pointer*, passing a non-pointer will not compile, so the question is moot.

The effect of passing a *pointer* that was not previously returned from a *heap allocation function* and not previously passed to `free()` is undefined - but never useful, or correct, and usually fatal.

In practice, `free()` will assume the pointer is a block allocated from the heap; the implementation may detect the error, or it may corrupt the heap.  The error may not be detected and will cause a failure undefined in nature at some later heap operation, making it very difficult to determine the original cause.

In a typical implementation allocated blocks are preceded by heap metadata; `free()` accesses this data by subtracting the size of the metadata from the pointer passed to it. For a non-heap allocated pointer, the data read will be invalid nonsense.  The implementation may be able to validate this data and cause a runtime error, but in a simple implementation, the metadata may contain just the size of the block, and a block of undefined size and inappropriate location may be added to the heap.