# Memory leak in JNI function Java_java_io_WinNTFileSystem_rename0?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I think the following function in the file jdk/src/windows/native/java/io/WinNTFileSystem_md.c in http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/promoted/b27/openjdk-6-src-b27-26_oct_2012.tar.gz neglects to free the memory used by `frompath` or `topath` if one of them is found to be `NULL`...

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_java_io_WinNTFileSystem_rename0(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jobject from,
                                 jobject to)
{

    jboolean rv = JNI_FALSE;
    WCHAR *frompath = fileToNTPath(env, from, ids.path);
    WCHAR *topath = fileToNTPath(env, to, ids.path);
    if (frompath == NULL || topath == NULL)
        return JNI_FALSE;
    if (_wrename(frompath, topath) == 0) {
        rv = JNI_TRUE;
    }
    free(frompath);
    free(topath);
    return rv;
}
```

Am I missing something?  Is this in fact a bug?

**Resolved:**  Looking further into the details of the function `pathToNTPath` in [io_util_md.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/tip/src/windows/native/java/io/io_util_md.c), I can see that `fileToNTPath` will only return `NULL` in the case of an out-of-memory error, so I guess we don't care if we neglect to free something we `malloc`ed when the JVM is about to crash! This still should be documented in the `Java_java_io_WinNTFileSystem_rename0` function in my opinion though.

Comment: You do not need to free the memory it something is null...

Comment: But what if one of them is NULL and the other isn't?  Then the non-NULL one won't get freed.

Comment: If you free a null in C nothing will happen no exception nothing. http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf So if one of them is null the next line will be executed...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938735/does-freeptr-where-ptr-is-null-corrupt-memory

Comment: And I am pretty sure this function has been tested by openjdk team.

Comment: No, this method will never try to free a NULL.  It will return without freeing a non-NULL when one of frompath and topath is NULL and the other isn't.  Please check the code carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved:**  Looking further into the details of the function `pathToNTPath` in [io_util_md.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/tip/src/windows/native/java/io/io_util_md.c), I can see that `fileToNTPath` will only return `NULL` in the case of an out-of-memory error, so I guess we don't care if we neglect to free something we `malloc`ed when the JVM is about to crash! This still should be documented in the `Java_java_io_WinNTFileSystem_rename0` function in my opinion though.

Answer (score 1):

I think the original point is valid. While the research into the other function used by this code does suggest that the problem might not be that important, this code is lacking when viewed in and of itself.

The general rule of code reviews is that if someone has a question, it should generally be answered in the code with at least a comment.

The general rule of comments is that if it can be expressed in code, it possibly should be.

All of these issues go away if the code is written to eliminate the question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from [`pathToNTPath()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/windows/native/java/io/io_util_md.c), which is called by `fileToNTPath()`, it returns NULL only in case of `OutOfMemoryException`, so I guess it's safe to assume that one does not need to take much care about freeing a few bytes of path name.