# Deallocates all of its memory and sets its head pointer to NULL (the empty list)

Tags: c, linked-list

Got a question in my exam.

Write a function `DeleteList`() that takes a list, deallocates all of its memory and sets its
head pointer to NULL (the empty list).

Solution was given as

```
void DeleteList(struct node** headRef) {
    struct node* current = *headRef;
    struct node* next;
    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next; 
        free(current); 
        current = next; 
    }
    *headRef = NULL;
}
```

My solution :

```
void DeleteList(struct node** headRef) {
    struct node* current = *headRef;

    while (current != NULL) {
        *headRef = *headRef->next;
         free(current);
         current = * headRef;
    }
    free(current);
    *headRef = NULL;
}
```

Is this correct approach?
Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried it, did it work?

Comment: I don't think that `*headRef->next` binds the way you think it does.

Comment: Apart from the precedence error - `*headRef = *headRef->next;` should be `*headRef = (*headRef)->next;`, it wouldn't compile otherwise - it's correct. But the `free(current);` after the while loop is superfluous and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not do this "and sets its head pointer to NULL" because the final line of your proposal (`*headRef = NULL;`) is no longer setting the incoming headRef value to NULL, but rather the final Next point in the list (which already is null).

Comment: The simplest way would be to declare and use a variable called `next` in place of `headRef`, as per the published solution, so that `headRef` is the correct location when the routine completes.

Answer (score 0):

```
free(current); //you should remove this line after the while loop because when while loop breaks the current is already NULL so free(NULL) makes no sense. 
*headRef = NULL;
```

look here [Free(NULL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938735/does-freeptr-where-ptr-is-null-corrupt-memory).

The rest must work according to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
void DeleteList(struct node **headRef)
{
    struct node *current = *headRef;

    while (current) {
         *headRef = (*headRef)->next;
         free(current);
         current = *headRef;
    }
    *headRef = NULL;
}
```