# Dynamic and continuous array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, dynamic, malloc

Is there anyway to make a 1D dynamic and continuous array using C++11?

I will take in the size of the array via `stdin` and once it's created it won't need to be resized.

Right now I am using a 1D vector of enums, and my biggest performance issue is the vector [] operator.

If it can't be done in C++, I am open to ways of doing it with `malloc` and C, just please note the best way to `delete` it.

Edit: Didn't realize vectors were night and day with debug and release. I reran callgrind with -O3 and now the issue is ostream not vectors - thanks to everyone who made me second guess myself before I rewrote it all using arrays when not needed.

Comment: That operation on a vector is generally not more costly than an index into an array.

Comment: Is the issue that you are using `enums`? Why are you not using regular integers?

Comment: I am using enums for readability, it's a 1 byte enum and I do bitwise operations on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    int size = 10;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]>  a(new int[size]);
```

Follows RAII (that is array is autodestructed)
However I don't think vector [] operator should be performance issue. In debug compilation it may be checked, however in release it should not.


In MSVC there is feature called checked iterators which may "kill" performance. However you're able to switch this feature off (just google it)

Answer (score 3):

You can always dynamically create contiguous homogeneous storage  of a certain type from the heap  using the new operator

```
Type *pType = new Type[size](initial_value)
```

In Order to delete the storage, you need to explicitly invoke the array delete operator

```
delete[] pType
```

But, when you say, `and my biggest performance issue is the vector [] operator.`, I doubt. Did you profile the retail version of your code? How do you know the vector subscript is your performance bottleneck?

Comment: +1 "I doubt. Did you profile the retail version of your code?"

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` has enough performance to use in production. It is used for solving problems on programming contests. Maybe, you forget to compile into release?

Also, you can use `new` and `delete` operators.

To free allocated memory use `free(void *ptr)` function.

Answer (score 0):

In C you create a 1-D array with

```
int *ptr=NULL;
int num_elements = 0;
printf("how many elements?\n");
if(scanf("%d", &num_elements)==1) {
  ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*num_elements);
  if(ptr == NULL) {
    printf("unable to allocate %d elements\n", num_elements);
    exit 0;
  }
}
```

and when you're done, you call

```
free(ptr);
```

Make sure you call it only once! Some people will do

```
if( ptr != NULL ) {
  free(ptr);
  ptr = NULL;
}
```

as defensive coding - prevents accidentally freeing it twice.

Comment: the if block is unnecessary - freeing a null pointer is totally okay.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938735/does-freeptr-where-ptr-is-null-corrupt-memory - "it was not always so". I recall running into crashed on freeing NULL (Borland C on PC in early 90's maybe). I suspect the "do nothing on `free(NULL)` standard wasn't always there.

Comment: the accepted answer in your linked question seems to support my point :)

Comment: @andreas - yes. But further down there are other observations... We both have a point but you are absolutely correct about the standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, using `malloc` is probably a poor (inferior) idea.

```
int length;
cin >> length;

MyType * array = new MyType[length];
```

Then to delete,

```
delete[] MyType;
```