# C Memory leak with valgrind

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm trying to implement a Queue using a linked list in C, in an open-source project. I'm at the point where I've implemented the Queue, wrote unit tests, and worked out most of the memory leaks using valgrind.

The problem now is that I've been trying to find the leak for these last 8 bytes for a couple hours now, and I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the output from valgrind:

```
==25806== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==25806==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==25806==    by 0x80484E3: node_create (in /home/karysto/c-datastructures/queue/tests.out)
==25806==    by 0x8048511: enqueue (in /home/karysto/c-datastructures/queue/tests.out)
==25806==    by 0x8048851: test_dequeue_updates_size (in /home/karysto/c-datastructures/queue/tests.out)
==25806==    by 0x8048978: test_suite (in /home/karysto/c-datastructures/queue/tests.out)
==25806==    by 0x80489B0: main (in /home/karysto/c-datastructures/queue/tests.out)
==25806== 
==25806== LEAK SUMMARY:
==25806==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==25806==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25806==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25806==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25806==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25806==
```

Here's my structs for the queue linked list:

```
struct Queue {
    int size;
    struct Node *front;
    struct Node *back;
};

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

Here's `queue.c`, the implementation for `dequeue`.

```
void
dequeue(struct Queue *q) {

    /* Dequeue from an empty queue. */
    if (q->size == 0) {
        return;
    }

    /* Dequeue the only node. */
    else if (q->size == 1) {
        q->front = NULL;
        q->back  = NULL;
        free(q->front);
        free(q->back);
    }

    /* Regular case. */
    else if (q->size > 1) {
        struct Node *temp;
        temp = q->front;
        q->front = q->front->next;
        free(temp);
    }

    --(q->size);
    return;
}
```

And here's the `enqueue` in the same file.

```
void
enqueue(struct Queue *q, int data) {
    struct Node *head = node_create(data);

    /* First enqueue on empty. */
    if (q->front == NULL && q->back == NULL) {
        q->front = head;
        q->back  = head;
    }

    else {
        q->back->next = head;
        q->back       = head;
    }

    ++(q->size);
    return;
}
```

For completness, here's the `node_create` function that is being referenced from `enqueue`:

```
struct Node*
node_create(int d) {
    struct Node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    n->data = d;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: `q->front = NULL; free(q->front)` - shouldn't that be the other way round? And aren't `q->front` and `q->back` the same in a single-node queue?

Comment: You're right in that the `q->front = NULL` should be after, but if I switch them around, the compilation produces a `*** glibc detected *** ./tests.out: double free or corruption (fasttop)` error.

Comment: Yes, that's the second logical error in your snippet. You can only free the same node once, no matter via which pointer you access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your problem lies in dequeuing the last node:

```
/* Dequeue the only node. */
else if (q->size == 1) {
    q->front = NULL;
    q->back  = NULL;
    free(q->front);
    free(q->back);
}
```

You effectively call `free(NULL)` twice. `free(NULL)` is allowed, but it doesn't do anything. So you end up not freeing the node and lose the memory. You should  assign `NULL` to the front and back after freeing and you should also `free` the last node only once:

```
/* Dequeue the only node. */
else if (q->size == 1) {
    free(q->front);
    q->front = NULL;
    q->back  = NULL;
}
```

(Here, the front and back are the same. You are also remobving at most one node when dequeuing, so you should only free at most one node.)

Comment: Thank you so much @M Oehm! Your explaination is clear and it fixed the memory leak :) I'll upvote that.

Comment: `free(NULL)` is _not_ the cause of the memory leak (it is a no-op), which may confuse readers. The cause is _omitting to free_ the node which is allocated.

Comment: @Betamos: `free(NULL)` leads to the memory leak, because the OP thought he'd freed the memory, but hadn't. I agree that the explanation was confusing and have rewritten it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/* Dequeue the only node. */
    else if (q->size == 1) {
        free(q->front);
        q->front = NULL;
        q->back  = NULL;
    }
```

Explanation: In your original solution you were first pointing both `q->front` and `q->back` to `NULL` before `free()`ing them. Running `free()` on `NULL` [doesn't destroy the universe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938735/does-freeptr-where-ptr-is-null-corrupt-memory) but it doesn't do very much, i.e. not `free()`ing your last node.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Betamos, it works! I chose Oehm's answer for the explanation behind it.