# Can someone help me understand why I'm getting segmentation fault in the below program

Tags: c

Please help me in understanding the below code, my expected output is "50".I'm able to get this output when I return pointer "s" from function "f" and in main I need to make this changes s= f(s,i).

```
void f(char *s,int i)
{
    s = (char*)malloc (20 *sizeof(char));
    s[i++]=50;
    s[i++]=53;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    char *s = NULL;
    f(s,i);
    printf(" s[%d]= %u \n",i,s[i]);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass `s` by reference.

```
void f(char **s,int i)
{
    *s        = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    (*s)[i++] = 50;
    (*s)[i++] = 53;
}

int main()
{
    int i   = 10;
    char *s = NULL;
    f(&s,i);
    printf(" s[%d]= %u \n", i, s[i]);
    free(s);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that in your case, after you return from `f(s, i);`, in `main()` the variable `s` is unchanged and therefore still `NULL`. The crash then occurs in the `printf(..., s[i]);` call. In particular note that `free(s)` will not crash because [`free` can also be passed `NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1938758/130580).

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Can I ask one more question??

Comment: Only if it starts with a vowel.

Comment: char * t(char *s1)
    {
        char *t = "pqrs";
        s1 = "fdsa";
        return t ;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        char *s = "abcde";
         s =t(s);
        printf("%s \n",s);
    
        return 0;
    }

output is pqrs : How can we return local pointer??

Comment: Pointers hold the address of memory location. Initially `pointer s` in `main` function have address of stating position of string `"abcd"`. Function `t` returns the address of pointer `t`, it replaces previous value of `s` in `main` function. Since pointer `t` is local to function `t` you can't access it outside of its scope. But in your code you make `s` in `main` to point to pointer `t`'s value, which is possible as local variables are stored in memory and memory is not restricted by scope. If somehow you can do that you will get restricted access error.