# Writing a safe wrapper class for memory management of a user-defined object's pointer

Tags: c++, hiredis

I'm using [redis c++ client](https://github.com/vipshop/hiredis-vip) to develop client APIs which will do CRUD operations on the redis cluster. The client library that I'm using returns a pointer of a `redisReply` structure whenever a command is executed. Later, I'm expected to use the `freeReplyObject()` function on the pointer to free the memory.

In order to develop a safer way, so that I inadvertently don't use `freeReplyObject()` on an invalid pointer, I'm thinking about writing a wrapper class:

```
class reply_wrapper
{
        public:
                redisReply* p_reply;
                reply_wrapper(redisReply* reply = NULL)
                {
                        p_reply=reply;
                }

                ~reply_wrapper()
                {
                        freeReplyObject(p_reply);
                }
};
```

I'm thinking about constructing an object of this class, whenever I will execute a command on the server. I think by doing this I no longer will have to free the memory manually. Is this approach correct here and is there a better approach?

*Please note that `freeReplyObject()` handles the case of `null` pointer.*

---

> I'm getting almost all the suggestions about using
>   shared-pointer/unique-pointer. While I check the examples available
>   online and see how it fits my scenario(custom destructor), I would
>   also like to know if there's anything fundamentally wrong in my method
>   of handling the memory above.

---

Comment: Can you use C++11?

Comment: Did you think about `unique_ptr` with `freeReplyObject` as custom destructor?

Comment: Yeah. I can use c++11.

Comment: @mch I don't know much about unique_ptr and how to define a custom destructor..I'll take a look.

Comment: It might be of a type such as `std::unique_ptr<redisReply, decltype(&freeReplyObject)>`.

Comment: Prefer constructor's initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`); with complex objects, you get direct initialisation while otherwise default-initialisation + assignment; some types (non-default-constructible ones, references) *only* can be initialised this way. (`reply_wrapper(redisReply* reply) : p_reply(reply) { }`).

Comment: As using C++11, you should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`).

Comment: @VishalSharma _" I don't know much about unique_ptr"_ [Here's](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) all you need to know.

Comment: In the code as is: Does `freeReplyObject` accept null pointers at all (C++ `delete` does, C's `free` function: UB!)? If not, you should add an appropriate check.

Comment: @Aconcagua  " if (r == NULL) return;" is in the beginning of freeReplyObject() definition.(r is the pointer here of redisReply type).

Comment: If you write your own, don't forget rule of 3/5.

Comment: @Aconcagua in C, `free(NULL)` is well-defined although some buggy runtime would not accept it (and crash). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1938758/5470596

Comment: @YSC Oh, fine, thanks for the hint...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, I've used `std::unique_ptr` and while constructing it I had to pass a functor which calls the `freeReplyObject` function in it.

```
struct redisReplyDeleterFunctor {
      void operator()(redisReply* p) {
          freeReplyObject(p);
      }
  };

unique_ptr<redisReply, redisReplyDeleterFunctor> reply((redisReply*)(redisClusterCommand(getDbContext(),  command.c_str())));
```

Now I don't need to call the `freeReplyObject()` manually and the memory will be automatically released as soon as my `unique_ptr` goes out of scope.

Comment: BTW, no need to define `redisReplyDeleterFunctor`. You could use `freeReplyObject` directly as: `unique_ptr<redisReply, void (*)(redisReply*)> reply(object, freeReplyObject);`. Also, you could use `decltype(freeReplyObject)` instead of `void (*)(redisReply*)`.