# Explanation about types and variables used in a malloc code

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I need some explanation for some commands in this particular piece of code:

```
#inlcude <stdlib.h>
#define PTRS 5

char *p[PTRS];

size_t nbytes = 10;
int i;
/* Allocating memory */
for (i=0; i<PTRS; i++){
    printf("malloc of %10lu bytes ", nbytes);

    if ((p[i] = (char *)malloc(nbytes)) == NULL){
        printf("failed\n");
    } else {
        printf("succeeded\n");
    nbytes *= 100;
}
/* Free the memory allocated */
for (i=0; i<PTRS; i++){
    if(p[i]){
        free(p[i]);
        p[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

**First one is**
`char *p[PTRS];`
Does this line declare a **pointer to an array** or does it declare **an array of *pointers*** to char?
`p[i] = (char *)malloc(nbytes)` I understand that as `i` increases, `p[i]` will contain a pointer to the allocated memory called by `malloc` if it's successfully processed, and `p[i] will be`NULL` if no such memory can be prepared.
**Second one is**

```
if (p[i]){
    free(p[i]);
    p[i] = NULL;
}
```

This only frees memory if `p[i]` has any value (in this case a pointer to the memory). What happens if we remove `if(p[i])` and only use `free(p[i]` and `p[i] = NULL`? Can we free a `NULL` pointer?

Comment: For your last question, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938735/does-freeptr-where-ptr-is-null-corrupt-memory)

Comment: Given `size_t nbytes`, your `printf("malloc of %10lu bytes ", nbytes);` invokes undefined behavior.  The proper format string for `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: Incidentally, casting `malloc()` is discouraged in modern C, since it can force code to compile even if `#include <stdlib.h`  (the header that declares `malloc()` and friends) and the common result is then undefined behaviour.     It was only ever necessary in (very old) versions of C that predated introduction of the `void` pointer into the language  (so `malloc()` returned `char *`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *p[PTRS];
```

is equivalent to

```
char *(p[PTRS]);
```

i.e. it's an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. A pointer to an array would be e.g.

```
char (*p)[PTRS];
```

The [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) could be helpful in deciphering declarations. As would using resource such as https://cdecl.org.

---

And you can pass a `NULL` pointer to [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) (it's a no-op) so the check isn't needed really.

Depending on the further use of `p`, the `p[i] = NULL` assignment might not be needed either.

Comment: Thank you! And also I just read that `free(NULL)` used to cause some problems on old systems, that's why they added the check.

Comment: @NVA - That's only a concern if you've managed to find VERY old compilers and library.  Even K&R C (first edition was in 1978, from memory, which predated ratification of the first C standard by over a decade) specified that `free(NULL)` had no effect.    There were a few libraries before K&R first edition which would crash on `free(NULL)` but those were considered bugs even by their vendors/developers so you'd be hard pressed to find a C compiler and library with that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that as i increases, p[i] will contain a pointer to the
>   allocated memory called by malloc

So if you understand this when it means that `p[i]` being an element of an array has the type `char *` because at least in the program there is explicit casting to this type of the`malloc` call in the if statement

```
 if ((p[i] = (char *)malloc(nbytes)) == NULL){
```

So this declaration

```
char *p[PTRS];
```

declares an array of `PTRS` elements with the tyoe `char *`. I advice to write such a declarations like

```
char * p[PTRS];
```

inserting a blank after the character `'*'`.

You may rewrite the declaration also the following way

```
char * ( p[PTRS] );
```

A pointer to an array of `PTRS` elements of the type `char` is declared the following way.

```
char ( *p )[PTRS];
```

> Can we free a NULL pointer?

More precisely it would be said may we use the function `free` with a null-pointer because we are not freeing a null pointer itself that in the context of your example has the automatic storage duration.

The answer is yes we may. A call of the function with a null pointer will have neither affect and is safe.

Thus this loop

```
for (i=0; i<PTRS; i++){
    if(p[i]){
        free(p[i]);
        p[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

may be rewritten like

```
for (i=0; i<PTRS; i++){
    free(p[i]);
    p[i] = NULL;
}
```