Using free on nested structs makes program crash
I was recently exploring ll the oop features of C, when i came to this issue. I want to create a game engine with C, so i use nested structs to organize ewerything. But when freeing the memory, the program crashes. I know i am probably making an error in the code, but it would really help me if someone would explain the issue.
Here is the code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Outer
{
    int Var;
    struct Inner
    {
        int Var;
    }*inner;
};




int Init(struct Outer *outer)
{
    outer = (struct Outer*) malloc(sizeof(struct Outer));
    outer->inner = (struct Inner*) malloc(sizeof(struct Inner));
    if(outer == NULL || outer->inner == NULL){printf("fail1\n");return 1;}
printf("Sucess1\n");
return 0;
}

int Exit(struct Outer *outer)
{
    if(outer != NULL)
    {
        printf("outer is null\n");
        if(outer->inner != NULL)
        {
            printf("inner is null");
            free(outer->inner);
        }
        free(outer);
    }
    
    
    if(outer != NULL || outer->inner != NULL){printf("fail2\n");return 1;}
printf("Sucess2\n");
return 0;
}


int main()
{
    struct Outer *outer;

    Init(outer);

    outer->Var = 1;
    outer->inner->Var = 2;

    Exit(outer);

printf("terminated");
return 0;
}

the output is only:
Sucess1

I was expecting the memory would free normally, but as you can see, the program doesn't reach the end.

If you want to use Init's parameter to pass a pointer of "struct Outer" by reference, you can rewrite Init into Init(struct **outer), then whenever you attempt to modify the pointer pointed by outer, you should write *outer = malloc(sizeof(struct Outer)); and so on. To access inner, just write (*outer)->inner. When you call Init in main, you call it like this Init(&outer). Also, note that calling free(outer) inside Exit won't automatically set the variable outer to NULL. You have to set it to NULL yourself after the free call.

You reference outer->inner after you free(outer).  Don't do that.

if(outer != NULL) { printf("outer is null\n") .... is an odd message.  Perhaps you meant "outer is not null", or perhaps it indicates a serious logic error.

Don't forget to terminate printf() format strings with a newline, essentially every time.  If you are building a line piecemeal, then the intermediate print operations don't want a newline, but otherwise, end the format string with a newline.

Parameters in C are pass by value.  That means that when outer is passed to Init, any changes made to the parameter within the function aren't seen outside the function.
This means that outer remains uninitialized after Init returns, and subsequent operations on it trigger undefined behavior in your code causing it to crash.
Change the Init function to return the allocated pointer:
struct Outer *Init()
{
    // don't cast the return value of malloc and perform error check right away
    struct Outer *outer = malloc(sizeof(struct Outer));
    if(outer == NULL) {
        printf("fail1\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    outer->inner = malloc(sizeof(struct Inner));
    if(outer->inner == NULL) {
        printf("fail1a\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Sucess1\n");
    return outer;
}

And change the call to assign the result:
outer = Init();

Also, this line in Exit is problematic:
if(outer != NULL || outer->inner != NULL){printf("fail2\n");return 1;}

The values of outer and outer->inner are not modified in the function.  The values of these variables are passed to free and, as before, passing by value doesn't change these variables.
So your attempt at checking these values to see if free was successful doesn't do what you expect.  This line should be removed entirely.

I disagree with dbush's solution. It is a valid solution so I won't downvote it, but it deviates from the OP's original API design: to return an int for status and use a pointer to allow the functions to return the function's output. There are many examples of this model. Since his question was a coding question, we should only modify the design if necessary. We can certainly suggest design modifications if we want to, but that should be secondary.
Earlier the OP had asked something to the effect of "I thought passing a pointer allowed you to modify what it contains." I wanted to give a bit more clarification here.
It is certainly true that you pass a pointer to variable or structure so that the called function can modify that variable or structure. However, remember that you have to pass a pointer to the thing you want to modify.
In this case, your main() declared a structure pointer:
    struct Outer *outer;

This pointer is not initialized, so the outer pointer variable itself contains garbage. Then you called Init(), passing the pointer. As has been explained elsewhere, the content of the parameter is passed by value on the stack. Thus, the Init() function has its own copy of the outer pointer, which it initializes with malloc. But that never makes it back to main()'s pointer.
What you intended was to pass a pointer TO the pointer variable (I'll also fix the error checking):
int Init(struct Outer **out_outer)
{
    struct Outer *loc_outer;  // Local copy of new structure.
    loc_outer = (struct Outer*)malloc(sizeof(struct Outer));
    if (loc_outer==NULL) { printf("fail1.1\n"); return 1; }
    loc_outer->inner = (struct Inner*) malloc(sizeof(struct Inner));
    if (loc_outer->inner == NULL) { printf("fail1.2\n"); free(loc_outer); return 1; }
    *out_outer = loc_outer;  // Return the new structure.
    printf("Sucess1\n");
    return 0;
}
...

Init(&outer);

I tested this modification and it works.
One final note: the Exit() function seems to be written to assume that when malloced memory is freed, the free function sets the pointer to NULL. This is not the case. So, for example, when I run the modified program I get:
Sucess1
outer is null
inner is nullfail2

The "fail2" is printed because the pointers are not null. In fact, the if statement at the end of Exit() is invalid. If the passed-in outer is null, the outer != NULL will be false, so it will attempt to check out->inner. This will dereference a null pointer leading to a segmentation fault. In fact, even with a non-null input, it is still illegal. Since the pointers are NOT set to null by free(), you are dereferencing freed memory. This would probably not raise an exception (it didn't for me), but is very dangerous and should be considered a bug.
You were trying to judge the success of the free() call by assuming it sets the pointer to null. But it can't because you aren't passing it a pointer to your pointer. Also, as free()'s man page indicates, it doesn't return a status either. In fact, you can't evaluate the success or failure of free(). This is one case where you just have to hope. :-)
Again, I think your idea is that when Exit() returns, main()'s outer pointer will be set to NULL. This is not a common model, by the way. But if you really want your Exit() function to have this behavior (also fixed the prints):
int Exit(struct Outer **out_outer)
{
    struct Outer *loc_outer = *out_outer;
    if(loc_outer != NULL)
    {
        printf("outer is not null\n");
        if(loc_outer->inner != NULL)
        {
            printf("inner is not null\n");
            free(loc_outer->inner);
            loc_outer->inner = NULL;
        }
        free(loc_outer);
        loc_outer = NULL;
    }

    // The following checks are unnecessary.
    if(loc_outer != NULL) {
        printf("fail2.1\n");
        if (loc_outer->inner != NULL) {
            printf("fail2.2\n");
        }
        return 1;
    }

    *out_outer = loc_outer;
    return 0;
}
...
Exit(&outer);

This gives me the following output:
Sucess1
outer is not null
inner is not null


Since the return value of both Init() and Exit() is ignored, I'm not sure that there is a major problem with dbush's answer w.r.t the Init() function.  However, he does not diagnose problems in the Exit() function as you do, so well done on that extra work.

Yeah, I noticed that too. I'm assuming the functions are a simplification of a real project he's working on, and his main() is just a test driver. Presumably his real code is checking return statuses. I felt that, as a teaching moment, he was confused about how pointers allow a sort of "pass by reference" parameter in C; pointers to pointers take a new programmer time to absorb.

Attempting a simple explanation, just consider:
int main()
{
    struct Outer *outer;
    Init(outer);
  

outer is not initialized.  Attempting to pass an uninitialized value to a function is undefined behavior, so there is no point analyzing any further than this.  Almost certainly, you intended to write:
int
main(void)
{        
    struct Outer *outer;
    Init(&outer);

If you want to change a local variable by calling a function, you must pass the address of the variable to the function.  The type of the variable is irrelevant.  You cannot change a variable by passing it to a function.  A pointer is a variable, and you cannot change a pointer by passing it to a function.  You can change a variable by passing its address to a function, and that holds true for pointer variables.  So you need to pass the address of the variable to Init in order to modify that variable in main.

There is merit to further analysis.  You can make changes to the code (mentally or physically) so that the uninitialized variable is initialized, and then critique (in particular) the Exit() function.

Thanks for the help. I wanted to keep the same design, because i wanted to be sure if i would be able to do it that way. I think the design is of course, secondary, but the knowledge is more important. This mistake had learned me a lot.

A more complete Init makes sure that it is in a valid state at each step when acquiring the two resources it needs to function. This allows it to return the state back to the original on intermediate success.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct Outer { int var; struct Inner { int var; } *inner; };

/** Destroys the pointed-at valid `pouter`, if not null. */
static void Outer_(struct Outer **const pouter) {
    struct Outer *outer;
    if(!pouter || !(outer = *pouter)) return;
    free(outer->inner); /* https://stackoverflow.com/q/1938735/2472827 */
    free(outer);
    *pouter = 0;
}

/** @return A fully initialized Outer.
 @throw `malloc` will return 0; `errno` will (probably) be set. */
static struct Outer *Outer(void) {
    struct Outer *outer = 0;
    if(!(outer = malloc(sizeof *outer))) goto catch;
    outer->var = 1;
    outer->inner = 0; /* This is important. */
    if(!(outer->inner = malloc(sizeof *outer->inner))) goto catch;
    outer->inner->var = 2;
    goto finally;
catch:
    Outer_(&outer);
finally:
    return outer;
}

static char temp_string[4][64]; /* Up to 4 short buffers for to strings. */
static unsigned temp_string_index;

static const char *OuterToString(const struct Outer *const outer) {
    char *str = temp_string[temp_string_index++];
    temp_string_index %= sizeof temp_string / sizeof *temp_string;
    if(!outer) sprintf(str, "null");
    else sprintf(str, "[%d[%d]]", outer->var, outer->inner->var);
    return str;
}

int main(void) {
    errno = 0;
    int ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
    struct Outer *outer = Outer();
    printf("%s.\n", OuterToString(outer));
    if(outer) ret = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    Outer_(&outer);
    printf("terminated; return %s.\n",
        ret == EXIT_SUCCESS ? "success" : "failure");
    if(errno) perror("last error");
    return ret;
}

The approximate control flow is thus one of tree things:
errno = 0;
struct Outer *outer;
errno = ENOMEM; /* In POSIX. */
outer = 0;
print "null.";
perror("last error");
return EXIT_FAILURE;

or
errno = 0;
outer = malloc(sizeof *outer));
outer->var = 1;
outer->inner = 0;
errno = ENOMEM; /* In POSIX. */
free(outer->inner); /* no-op */
free(outer);
outer = 0;
print "null.";
perror("last error");
return EXIT_FAILURE;

or
errno = 0;
outer = malloc(sizeof *outer));
outer->var = 1;
outer->inner = 0;
outer->inner = malloc(sizeof *outer->inner);
outer->inner->var = 2;
print "[1[2]].";
free(outer->inner);
free(outer);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;

This is overkill in a simple example; the intermediate memory-leak (in addition to it being very unlikely) is quickly forgotten when it returns to the operating system. However, longer-running or more complicated resource requirement programmes may need to consider what happens when one of many resources fails.
