# Does a pointer need to be nulled after it is freed?

Tags: c

```
int main(){

(int*) pointer = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
free(pointer);

}
```

I learned from 'Prata, Stephen. C Primer Plus (Developer's Library)' that
*"When the function terminates, the pointer, being an automatic variable, disappears."*  so simply, i don't need to null the pointer

however, I also learned from school that the pointer becomes a dangling pointer if it doesn't get nulled after it free.

Two ideas are contradicting each other. Which one is the right one?

Comment: `pointer` is a dangling pointer, but what does it matter? It goes out of scope right after anyway.

Comment: Dangling pointers are not a problem, as long as you don't use them. You can have a dangling pointer in a variable, and then reuse the variable to point somewhere else.

Comment: For what I know, setting it to null is a kind of "safe" gate, so that later you can still use it in comparison without having memory errors with ```if (pointer == null)```

Comment: you need to free the pointer,. that's the better approach

Comment: [Should one really set pointers to `NULL` after freeing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879550/should-one-really-set-pointers-to-null-after-freeing-them), and literally at least a dozen others on a similar line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2):

> The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

Therefore, you don't need to set pointer to `nullptr` (in C++11) or `NULL` (in C and before C++11) if it goes out of scope immediately after you `free` it because then you have no chance to dereference a dangling pointer.

However, if the pointer is still in the scope after a call to `free`, than the good practice would be to set it to `nullptr` or `NULL` so that the following checks would work:

**C++:**

```cpp
if (nullptr != ptr) {...}
```

**C:**

```c
if (NULL != ptr) {...}
```

**C and C++:**

```cpp
if (!ptr) {...}
```

Comment: I like the implicit conversion of pointer types to bool: ` if(ptr) {...}`, or, if you want to check the need to initialize it, `if(!ptr) { /* init ptr */ }`. (I realize that this is C++; I'm sure it works on major C environments but not sure about the standard.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica good point. I will add that too

Comment: That "documentation" is incorrect. The value of the pointer variable after `free` becomes **indeterminate**. Source: the C standard.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala how do you mean indeterminate? Doesn't it mean indeterminate _points to the same (now invalid) location_? Can you please send me your source of the C standard so i can update my answer?

Comment: @NutCracker [The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala cannot access this link

Comment: @NutCracker fixed, port70 is serving an invalid TLS certificate so using http works.

Comment: Consider referring to those pages: [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free)  or [`std::free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free). I *usually* find that site more accuarte. Also note the references to the relevant part of the standards at the bottom of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

What free does is to deallocate the space that pointer holds before the execution of free. The pointer holds an integer value(the address) before and after the execution therefore the address that the pointer holds is now an invalid address that is not allocated by the program. As said, if you plan to use the pointer again in future cases, you wouldn't wanna have an invalid undefined value in it that you cannot check, having null makes the checks easier.