# Can I call malloc() on a pointer twice (after freeing it)?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

So, I know we shouldn't try to access freed memory.
e.g.

```
int * x = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
free(x);
x[0] = 2; // results in data corruption
```

Most posts such as [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879550/should-one-really-set-pointers-to-null-after-freeing-them) say not to reuse pointers period. After calling free(), can I call malloc() (or calloc()) again on the same pointer? My understanding is that it will point to a new, unused section of memory now and be fine.
e.g.

```
int * x = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
free(x);

x = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
x[0] = 2;
```

what about if the previous memory location of the pointer is used by other variables now? e.g.

```
int * x = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
free(x);

... stuff happens here ...

x = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
x[0] = 2;
```

Comment: malloc and calloc assigns you a new pointer each time you call it.  So you aren't re-using a pointer. You're getting an entirely new address value assigned to x.  In other words, the value of `int* x` changes every time you invoke calloc. With the latter two examples provided above, you are good.

Comment: Or to put it succinctly, `x` is an entirely new pointer each time you malloc/calloc.

Comment: you can reuse a pointer *variable*, what you cannot do is access the same memory location that was pointed at after you have freed that location.

Comment: The concept of calling `malloc` "on a pointer" is meaningless.  You don't pass it a pointer.  It returns a pointer. Whether you choose to assign the returned pointer to a variable that you previously used for something else is entirely up to you.  Your question seems to be "Can I reuse pointer variables?"  And the answer is "Yes, of course you can."

Comment: if anyone thinks the question was decent, please upvote. I'm poor in rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer only stores the value returned by `malloc` and this function does not know anything about this pointer.

You can assign pointer as many times as you need with the value returned by the `malloc` function if you `free` previously stored value, otherwise you will have a memory leak.

```
void foo(void)
{
    char *ptr;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        ptr = malloc(rand() % 1000000);
        free(ptr);
    }
}
```